# Meteor config import .md files

Tags: mongodb, vue.js, meteor, mongoose

I'm base on `Meteor + Vue`. Try to import `.md` files to render to vue template

```js
<template>
 ..........
</template>
<script>

import mdFile from './README.md'
export default {
  name: 'VueMarkdown',
  data() {
    return {
      fileContent: '',
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getMDFile()
  },
  methods: {
    getMDFile() {
      this.fileContent = mdFile
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

but it's got error

```js
[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve async component: function () {
    return module.dynamicImport('./Vue-Markdown.vue');
  }
Reason: Error: Cannot find module './README.md'
```

Structure (meteor structure) :
Structure (Meteor structure) :

```
cleint/
   .........
server/
  ..........
import/
     module/
          client/
               pages/ 
                   vue-markdown.vue
                   README.md
                   ..........
          server/
             ...........
........
```

I don't know how to config it , can you help me?

Comment: What is the error you are getting? What's the code where that error is thrown? I don't think we'll be able to help much without more detail.

Comment: It's say error : 
```js
[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve async component: function () {
    return module.dynamicImport('./Vue-Markdown.vue');
  }
Reason: Error: Cannot find module './README.md' 
```
on vue template when I import `README.md` and `.md` file in same directory

Comment: can you show the doe where you are trying to import the `.md` file?

Comment: On vue template : 
```js
<template>
 ..........
</template>
<script>

import mdFile from './README.md'
export default {
  name: 'VueMarkdown',
  data() {
    return {
      fileContent: '',
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getMDFile()
  },
  methods: {
    getMDFile() {
      this.fileContent = mdFile
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: great, thanks; next, i think we'll need to see the directory layout, i.e., where this code lives relative to the `README.md` file

Comment: Structure (Meteor structure) : 
```
cleint/
   .........
server/
  ..........
import/
     module/
          client/
               pages/ 
                   vue-markdown.vue
                   README.md
                   ..........
          server/
             ...........
........
```